# Why does Commerce Cloud Sandbox show no page types on creation?

Tags: commerce-cloud

When I create a Commerce Cloud Sandbox, go to the Business Manager, and go look at the storefront, I can see a basic, starting UI. However, when I then go to Page Designer, it tells me that there are no page types available. How can the starting UI exist without any pages or page types? How can I edit the starting UI?

Comment: Have you imported the latest SFRA? and not the standard Ref App? SFRA ships with inlcuded page designer page types: [SFRA-Optimized Pages and Components for Page Designer](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.sfra_rn_release4_0__W6404974_page_designer_la.htm&type=5)

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a site in the Business Manager, then import the site data into it.

The sandbox allows you to generate demo content through the Site Import process. It's not done by default when you create a site because one could prefer to work on an empty site without demo data.